# How can i pass a pirce of HTML content into a stateless react component?

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a simple React component that wraps the given HTML content into a tag that serves as a context in which the content is displayed.

```
function Content(content) {
   return <div>{content}</div>;
}

<Content>
   <span>Hey!</span>
</Content>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is [`React.Children.xxx`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children) the thing you're looking for?

Comment: I guess you need something like this:
function Content(props) {
   return <div>{props.children}</div>;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Content(props) {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
}
```

Using ES6 syntax:

```
const Content = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple React component that wraps the given HTML content.

```
var content = "<Content><span>Hey!</span></Content>"


function Content() {
 return (
     <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 
     content}}>
     </div>
   );
}
```